# How to use <foreach> statement in @SelectProvider class with MyBatis3

Tags: java, sql, dynamic, foreach, mybatis

I am trying to use `@SelectProvider` to create dynamic SQL by including the use of the tag `foreach` for a `IN` clause. I know how to use it using the `@Select` annotation into my mapper.

The problem is that when I translate the SQL into the SQLProvider it seem that the use it of the tag directly is not processed for the proxy that invoke SQLProvider method to get the SQL.

Here is the code example by using the `@Select`:

```
// imports...

public interface MyMapper {
    @Select({"<script>",
        "SELECT col_1, col_2", 
        "FROM table_1",
        "WHERE col_3 IN",
            "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='items'",
                "open='(' separator=',' close=')'>",
                "#{item}",
            "</foreach>",
        "</script>"})
    HashMap<String, Object> select(@Param("items") String[] items);
}
```

The code above actually works, but when I try to use the `@SelectProvider` it doesn't works.

This is the code when I use @SelectProvider:

```
// imports...

public interface MyMapper {
    @SelectProvider(type = MySQLProvider.class, method = "select")
    HashMap<String, Object> select(@Param("items") String[] items);
}

public class MySQLProvider {
    public String select() {
        SQL sql = new SQL();
        sql.SELECT("col_1");
        sql.SELECT("col_2");
        sql.FROM("table_1");
        sql.WHERE("col_3 IN"
            + "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='items'"
                + "open='(' separator=',' close=')'>"
                + "#{item}"
            + "</foreach>");
        return "<script>" + sql.toString() + "</script>";
    }
}
```

When I use the `MyMapper` it process the SQL well but ignore the `script` and `foreach` statements.

Could anyone provide a concrete solution including the code?

Comment: Is this Java that you are using to build the dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yes, I am using Java 7 with MyBatis annotations to build Mappers.

Answer (score 3):

As of MyBatis 3.5.1, `<script>` blocks defined in SqlProvider methods can now be processed. Your posted code should work if you upgrade to this version.

See the first bullet point under enhancements on the release notes [here](https://blog.mybatis.org/2019/04/mybatis-351-released.html).